# iphone hides all music and app storage in windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, iphone

I just wondered this and seems no one ever asked, I searched online with all possible words combinations but no result.

My question is, seems years before you can directly access the content (music, etc) in your iphone, in windows on windows explorer. You plug in the phone, and it detects and shows your iphone, you click in it, and there is a internal storage, you click in it again, then there are all the musics and stuff, all hidden and randomly named with cipher code tho, you can still copy it out from your iphone directly under the show hidden files option in windows explorer.
But nowadays, it doesn't work anymore, you go into your internal storage and there is only your content from camera raw, all musics and other stuff is hidden, gone, even you select show hidden files option it will not work. This has been a long time (more than 2 years?) and I was always wondering why is it so but just never bother to ask, until today I have need to extract my music from my iphone, which doesn't work without a special tool. I understand apple do this due to copyright issues but how is it technically possible to do so? And how to solve it if there is a way other than using a special tool to extract it (also an short explanation of how those tools work will be appreciated). But most unfathomable, how is it possible that no one asks this on google since I don't get a single search results regarding this?

Anyway has any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to root your phone to get pure access to these files.  There are plenty of *how-to-root-my-iphone* out there.  Apple encrypts these files and limits access for a few reasons: including copyright infringement.

*(IMHO)* **Your easiest solution:  download iTunes and perform a backup of your data.**